# how do I "refresh" my docker desktop to get it to show new containers I have created?

Tags: docker

I have a running docker desktop (on MacOS if that matters).  And I have used the command line (in a terminal) to create some containers.  Ones that I created before running docker desktop show up in the "containers/apps" list, but more recent ones don't.  How do I "refresh" the list of containers to show these new ones.  I don't want to stop/start the actual running containers.  I just want a current list of them in the desktop app.

Comment: There's an issue open for this in the docker/for-win repo: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9401  I just added a post there. Maybe if you do also, it will help raise the priority.

Comment: *Thank you.*  I added my question to the list of comments on that issue.  Even if I had to hit a button (and there was such a button), I would be ok with it.

Comment: It also doesn't show containers you've downloaded, whether they're running or not.. and there's no apparent way to manually add them. What's the point of this app?